# Can a bivariate polynomial be increasing in one non-zero direction only?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, roots

Consider a bivariate polynomial 
$$f(x,y)=\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^m b_{ij}x^iy^j$$
defined on $[0,1]^2$. Suppose that on $[0,1]^2$ this polynomial weakly increases in direction $d=(d_1,d_2) \neq 0$: 
$$d_1 \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} + d_2 \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} \geq 0.$$

My question is whether it is possible to have a situation when such $d$ is *the only non-trivial direction of monotonicity*  of $f$? That is, if there is another $\tilde{d} \neq 0$ such that $f$ is increasing in direction $\tilde{d}$  on $[0,1]^2$ then it has to be that 
$$\tilde{d}=\alpha d $$
for some $\alpha>0$?

Comment: Polynomials have continuous derivatives (of all orders), so if you perturb the direction $d=(d_1,d_2)$ the directional derivative will be positive not only instantaneously at $(x,y)$ but in a "directional neighborhood" (local cone) at that point.  Perhaps I've misunderstood the problem, but it seems you assume locally increasing in direction $d$ at every point $(x,y) \in [0,1]^2$.

Comment: Thanks @hardmath. Yes, I assume locally increasing in direction $d$. But the directional derivative could take the value of zero (potentially for many points $(x,y)$ so I am not sure whether the perturbation argument would apply in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured out an asnwer to my question. Yes, it can happen. E.g., it seem that the polynomial
$$f(x,y)=x y(1-y), \quad (x,y) \in [0,1]^2$$
is increasing in the direction $d=(1,0)$ only.